# Check for absence of data

Tags: sql

I've been racking my brains on how i can achieve the below so any help would be greatfully received.

I've a table of sessions that run for a doctors clinic. The columns used are
Clinic ID, Session ID, Session Date.
Example data would be

```
Clinic_ID | Session_ID | Session_Date
    1     |     1      |  20160114
    1     |     2      |  20160121
    1     |     3      |  20160128
    2     |     1      |  20160114
    2     |     2      |  20160128
```

The Clinic_ID links to a Clinic table where it stores the main details for the clinic. The relationship being that one clinic can have many sessions against it.

The data i'm trying to retrieve is for any clinic which has a session running on a Session_Date with 20160121, but doesn't have a session running on the 20160128.

I just really don't know where to start on writing a query for this one - if i've been too vague or missing information, please let me know and i'll provide the best i can.

Tables names are Clinic_List for Clinics and Sessions_List for the Sessions.

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: My initial thought was around the below, but this obviously doesn't work as the intial select would find any session not running on 20160128    SELECT Clinic_List.CLINIC_ID FROM Clinic_List
INNER JOIN Session_List
ON Clinic_List.CLINIC_ID=Session_List.CLINIC_ID
WHERE SESSION_DATE <>'20160128' AND Session_List.CLINIC_ID IN
(SELECT Session_List.CLINIC_ID FROM Session_List
WHERE SESSION_DATE='20160121')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this is using `group by` and a `having` clause:

```
select clinic_id
from Sessions_List
group by clinic_id
having sum(case when session_date = 20150121 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when session_date = 20160128 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

I like this approach (using the `having` clause) because it is quite flexible for a wide range of conditions.  Each expression in the `having` clause is counting the number of sessions on a given date.  The `> 0` means there is a session; `= 0` means there is not.

Comment: This worked brilliantly. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  distinct Clinic_ID
from    Session_List
where   Session_Date = '20160121'
        and Clinic_ID not in
        (
        select  Clinic_ID
        from    Session_List
        where   Session_Date = '20160128'
        )
```